# How do I get the line count of an embedded Monaco editor in React? (including wrapping)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

I want  to extract the line count, including the wrapping, out of an embedded monaco editor in React. Here is a dummy setup:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Editor from '@monaco-editor/react'; 


function ExampleApp() {
  const customHTMLRef = useRef(null);
  const [lineCount, setLineCount = useState();

  function handleHTMLEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    customHTMLRef.current = editor;
  }
}

return (
  <>
    <Editor 
      theme='vs-dark'
      height='100%'
      width='100%'
      defaultLanguage='html'
      onMount={handleHTMLEditorDidMount}
    />
    <div>Line Count is: {lineCount}</div>
  </>
)
```

Some resources I was using, maybe you can see what I dont:

https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/947

https://codepen.io/monir/pen/72958128d822b228ba0245b16171c293?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it seems that they removed the method to retreive line count with wraps. But you still can count lines using the getLineCount() method. As you can see in the first ref that you show. Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-gates-9zf5q?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: The example you provided worked for my project perfectly! Thanks!